# in scala how do we aggregate an Array to determine the count per Key and the percentage vs total

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate, rdd

I am trying to find an efficient way to find the following :

1. Int1 = 1 or 0, Int2 = 1..k (where k = 3) and Double = 1.0
2. I want to find how many 1 or 0 are there in every k
3. I need to find the percentage of result of 3 on the total of the size of the Array??

Input is :

```
  val clusterAndLabel = sc.parallelize(Array((0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 1), (2, 0)))
```

So in this example:

1. I have :   0,0 = 2 , 0,1 = 0
2. I have :   1,0 = 1 , 1,1 = 1
3. I have :   2,1 = 2 , 2,0 = 1

Total is 7 instances

I was thinking of doing some aggegation but I am stuck on the thought that they are both considered 2-key join

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find how many 1 and 0s there are you can do:

```
val rdd = clusterAndLabel.map(x => (x,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

this will give you an `RDD[(Int,Int),Int]` containing exactly what you described, meaning: `[((0,0),2), ((1,0),1), ((1,1),1), ((2,1),2), ((2,0),1)]`. If you really want them gathered by their first key, you can add this line:

```
val rdd2 = rdd.map(x => (x._1._1, (x._1._2, x._2))).groupByKey()
```

this will yield an `RDD[(Int, (Int,Int)]` which will look like what you described, i.e.: `[(0, [(0,2)]), (1, [(0,1),(1,1)]), (2, [(1,2),(0,1)])]`.

If you need the number of instances, it looks like (at least in your example) `clusterAndLabel.count()` should do the work.

I don't really understand question 3? I can see two things:

- you want to know how many keys have 3 occurrences. To do so, you can start from the object I called `rdd` (no need for the groupByKey line) and do so:

  ```
  val rdd3 = rdd.map(x => (x._2,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
  ```

  this will yield and `RDD[(Int,Int)]` which is kind of a frequency RDD: the key is the number of occurences and the value is how many times this key is hit. Here it would look like: `[(1,3),(2,2)]`. So if you want to know how many pairs occur 3 times, you just do `rdd3.filter(_._1==3).collect()` (which will be an array of size 0, but if it's not empty then it'll have one value and it will be your answer).
- you want to know how many time the first key 3 occurs (once again 0 in your example). Then you start from `rdd2` and do:

  ```
  val rdd3 = rdd2.map(x=>(x._1,x._2.size)).filter(_._1==3).collect()
  ```

  once again it will yield either an empty array or an array of size 1 containing how many elements have a 3 for their first key. Note that you can do it directly if you don't need to display `rdd2`, you can just do:

  ```
  val rdd4 = rdd.map(x => (x._1._1,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).filter(_._1==3).collect()
  ```

  (for performance you might want to do the filter before `reduceByKey` also!)

Comment: There's a missing right paren on this line: val rdd2 = rdd.map(x => (x._1._1, (x._1._2, x._2)).groupByKey()